# Search Bar in Thesis Wordpress Site

Tags: css

A friend of mine installed all the Thesis documentation for my new website. I am fairly proficient in HTML and CSS, but I need help with one issue. She tried adding a search bar in my main menu structure--which you will notice is totally random. I added a search widget instead. Where or how do I delete the incorrect search bar (it's in the top right corner of my site)? I can't figure out where it is coded into the site or how to remove it.

The site is: www.ladidacreative.com

Answer (score 2):

The incorrect search is found under nav_container and is the second node `div.search`.

Deleting the div with the search class ( `div.search` ) will remove that search bar and all the elements that came with it.

[image: In chrome inspector]